# Writing permutations as products of disjoint cycles (left to right)

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

I've always done it from right to left but the book I'm currently using does it the other way around.
Could someone please explain the process?
Also I read here that answer for (1 2)(1 3) varies depending on the convention.
I know there are many similar questions here but I can't say I understood any of the answers.

For example (1 2) (1 3) (1 4) and (4 5 2 1 3)(2 4 5 6)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it goes  for the product of three transpositions:

- $1\mapsto 2$; the following transpositions leave $2$ fixed, so globally $\color{red}{1\mapsto 2}$.
- $2\mapsto 1$, then $1\mapsto 3$, which is fixed by the last transposition, so globally, $\color{red}{2\mapsto 3}$.
- $3\mapsto 3\mapsto 1\mapsto 4$, so $\color{red}{3\mapsto 4}$.
- $4\mapsto 4\mapsto 4\mapsto 1$, so $\color{red}{4\mapsto 1}$.

Therefore, we obtain the cycle
$\enspace(1\:2\:3\:4)$.

Comment: Isn't the answer for right to left (1 4 3 2) which is equivalent to (4 3 2 1) which is different permutation than (1 2 3 4)? Does permutation really depends on convention?

Comment: The answer proceeding from right to left is indeed $(1\,4\,3\,2)$ (one always start conventionally from the smallest element). Thus the other convention yields the inverse cycle. Note the normal convention is what you used, as it reflects the fact that a product of permutations corresponds to a composition of maps.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense